# Multi language using Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Confuse to use multi language using codeigniter.

Example, 
my domain is `www.example.com`
then I have 3 language, English (en), Japan (jp), China (cn)
and now I need access every language like:

```
www.example.com/en/bla-bla/
www.example.com/jp/bla-bla/
www.example.com/cn/bla-bla/
```

but, I dont want make controller every language.
have you idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use routing to pass language as variable to your controller to display content in correct language. For example you can do it like that:
In *application\config\routes.php*

```
$route['(:any)/product'] = 'product/index/$1';
```

In controller:

```
class Product extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index($lang = '') {
        //for link http://example.com/en/product there will be 'en' in $lang
    }
}
```

Documentation:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: it's use _lang_ in folder, how to use if in database?

Comment: This example pass $lang as variable to your controller so you can use it to create query to your database.

Comment: You should also check language class:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html