# codeigniter redirecting to a url

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes, uri

I have a website with a url like so (which works fine)

```
http://www.page.com/en/controller
```

But there always have to be a language and a controller in the url otherwise the page doesn't load or there is no language (no text).

Is it possible that when I enter a url like this

```
http://www.page.com
```

I get redirected to

```
http://www.page.com/en/controller
```

And the controller would be hidden? Only this would be left (my links require first segment to load a page with a particular language)

```
http://www.page.com/en
```

p.s tried routing and redirect, but with no luck

Sorry for the late response, I was away.

my routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'arena/display';



$route['(:any)/renginiai'] = "renginiai/getevents";
$route['(:any)/arena'] = "arena/display";
$route['(:any)/paslaugos'] = "paslaugos/displayServices";
$route['(:any)/kontaktai'] = "kontaktai/displayContacts";

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

My_Controller which is located in core folder. I load my language libraries from here.

```
/**
* 
*/
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $languages = array("lt", "en");

        if(in_array($this->uri->segment(1), $languages)){
            $this->lang->load($this->uri->segment(1), $this->uri->segment(1));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my front page controller

```
<?php
class Arena extends MY_Controller{

    public function display($year = NULL, $month = NULL){


        /*$this->load->model('Mycal_model');*/

        $this->load->model('Image_model');


        $data['images'] = $this->Image_model->get_image_data();


        $this->load->view('includes/head');
        $this->load->view('includes/nav', $data);
        $this->load->view('includes/header', $data);
        //$this->load->view('includes/calendar', $data);
        $this->load->view('includes/section');
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your default controller and how do you behave if the language variable is empty? 
You could try having a .htaccess if you're using apache

Comment: Show to us your controller and your router.php setting..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi language using Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088433/multi-language-using-codeigniter)

Comment: That is one of the problems i would like to fix. When my language variable is empty, there is no text in the page and naturally all of my links doesnt work. Because they take the first segment as a paremeter to load other page in the same language. If that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

open application/config/routes.php file and change

```
$route['default_controller'] = "en/controller";
```